# GeoServer serves a TIFF file in an Azure Blob

Tags: geoserver

Can GeoServer publish a TIFF file stored in an Azure Blob. i.e the TIFF file is not on the same machine of GeoServer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet, support for that should be coming in 2.19.0 (along with the effort for efficient S3 support).